# ZK datatables and accessibility

Tags: accessibility, zk

I should correct some accessibility issues in a ZK application, and I found the following problem: the components Grid and Listbox with headers generates two HTML table tags, one for the content and one for the headers. It seems not to be conform with accessibility guidelines.

What is the advantage of this approach? Is there such a datatable solution in ZK that generates only one HTML table tag, where the connection between header cells and data cells are more clear?

Answer (score 0):

After some googling I've got the answer:

- The technique of using separate table for headers is an old solution for scrollable table content with fix (sticky) table headers. At present you can find several pure CSS solution for it and you do not need the two-tables-solution.
- I could not find any alternative solution in ZK where a single table is used. They need this solution perhaps for other aims.
- For acessibility, we have to use ARIA roles to bind the two tables, like in the example at https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/10/notes-on-fixing-incorrect-table-structure-using-aria/